# Login Form for PHP Application

Tags: php, sql, database, authentication, azure-sql-database

I am working on an application which I am creating using HTML and PHP and I am trying to get a contact form to work for it but getting HTTP errors.

I am using an Azure SQL database and I have tried the below but it won't seem to work. I have created an html form to read in the username and password and then I have a separate file which I intend to read in the username and password and test if they match the values in the users table in my database. If not the form will clear and they will type in new credentials. Can anyone spot the issue here ? My code is :

login_page.html :

```
 <html>
 <head>
<title>Login</title>
 </head>
 <body>

<br>
<br>

<center><div class="container">
<a href=""><img src="L.jpg" alt="DCU" style="width:200px;height:200px;"></a>
<br>
<a href=""><img src="LN.jpg" alt="DCU" style="width:400px;height:90px;"></a>
 <br>
<br>

<form action="verify.php">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-25">
    <label for="User Name">Username</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-75">
    <input type="text" name="Username" placeholder="Username">
  </div>
</div>
 <br>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-25">
    <label for="Password">Password</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-75">
    <input type="password" name="Password" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  </div>
  <br>
<div class="row">
  <input type="submit" value="Login">
 </div>
 </form>
</div></center>



</body>
</html>
```

verify.php

```
 <?php 
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 
 $serverName = "xxxx";
 $options = array(  "UID" => "xxx",  "PWD" => "xxxx",  
 "Database" => "xxxx");
 $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $options);

 if( $conn === false )
 {
 echo "Could not connect.\n";
 die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
 }  


$usr = $_POST['username']; 
$pas = = $_POST['password']; 
$sql = sqlsrv_query("SELECT username FROM dbo.users  
    WHERE username='$usr' AND 
    password='$pas' 
    LIMIT 1"); 
if(sqlsrv_num_rows($sql) == 1){ 
    $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($sql); 
    session_start(); 
    $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username']= TRUE; 
    header("Location: index.html"); 
    exit; 
    }else{ 
    header("Location: login_page.html"); 
    exit; 
     } 
     }else{    //If the form button wasn't submitted go to the index 
     page, or login page 
     header("Location: login_page.html");     
     exit; 
      } 
     ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML, you aren't setting the method of form to be `POST` (which is incredibly important for handling sensitive data). Because there's no method defined, it will default to `GET`, meaning that your PHP code will never run past the first conditional; it's looking to receive a `POST` request but that isn't what is being passed in.

If you add the following to your form tag, it should work (or at least print something to you):

`<form action="verify.php" method="post">`

Comment: I made that adjustment and am still getting a HTTP ERROR 500

Answer (score 0):

Please enable [Diagnostics Logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log) that will help you get more detailed errors at the Web server level and application level error. You can also use Visual Studio [debug mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/Azure/app-service/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio) remotely to create traces and obtain detailed error messages.